# Activity cannot stop another activity and then itself

Tags: android

I have 2 Activities, **A** and **B**.

A invokes B with an intent and request code  -

```
startActivityForResult(i,123);
```

... later I want A to stop B and then itself, so in A I did

```
finishActivity(123);
finish();  // finish itself
```

... but B doesn't stop!   BUT if I set breakpoints at all the onStop's and onDestroy's and step through in the debugger everything works perfectly and both Activities go away.  (this suggests a timing or race condition)

However if I comment-out A's finish() ...

```
finishActivity(123);
// finish();  // finish itself
```

B does finish but A doesn't because its finish has been taken away.    What is the correct way to have one activity finish another one that it created, and then finish itself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are starting B for a result why would you not want to let it end itself and send the result back to A? If you are correct about timing then you could use a runnable and postDelayed to delay the finsh() by half a second or whatever it needs

Comment: instead of using finishActivity(123) from A try having an instance of B saved (not recommended, memory) and call a method inside B that will close itself so that you get the onActivityResult called

Comment: This is for an industrial application where the Android device is a remote control for a PC-based industrial process.  Messages on the PC are displayed on both the PC and Android device and the user can interact or dismiss them from either.  The case I'm describing is where the message was handled on the PC so the Android device needs to dismiss it sans user-interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this works:

```
finishActivity(123);
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        finish();
    }
});
```

The reason I suggest this is that I think the call to `finish()` is not giving `finishActivity(123)` a chance to do its thing. By calling `runOnUiThread`, the call to `finish()` will take place on the next loop through the UI message queue.